# How to understand the regular expressions while doing any validations

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this reg expression for email validation. But it's not clear me what it's doing and difficult for me to understand what is this Regular Expression doing and how can I learn to understand it.

```
[a-z0-9]+([-+._][a-z0-9]+){0,2}@.*?(\.(a(?:[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|ero|(?:rp|si)a)|b(?:[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]iz)|c(?:[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz]|at|o(?:m|op))|d[ejkmoz]|e(?:[ceghrstu]|du)|f[ijkmor]|g(?:[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|ov)|h[kmnrtu]|i(?:[delmnoqrst]|n(?:fo|t))|j(?:[emop]|obs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m(?:[acdeghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|il|obi|useum)|n(?:[acefgilopruz]|ame|et)|o(?:m|rg)|p(?:[aefghklmnrstwy]|ro)|qa|r[eosuw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]|t(?:[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|(?:rav)?el)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])\b){1,2}
```

Comment: Though over SO, we are not suppose to recommend, try [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kH8pnd/1). They have good section explaining what you are doing and you can even add sample inputs to validate

Comment: https://jex.im/regulex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `https://regex101.com` set it to the correct Flavor in your case ECMAScript (Javascript) and it will give you a break down of what it's doing in the Explanation box,[image: Example of Regex101]

While I was writing this and getting the screenshot it appears @Rajesh added this as a comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

To teach how to understand regex is not possible in a single answer. What I suggest is that you go through tutorials found online, one ex. of such is https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285.

Or you can go to Udemy https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-regular-expressions-in-online-regex-course/

or as suggested by Martin Barker in another answer, you can go to https://regex101.com and get a detailed explanation of what your regex means.

Comment: Your answer was valid before please don't steal other answers without actual credit to try and get yours accepted over others we're supposed to support the community not snipe from them.

Comment: @MartinBarker Here goes your credit Sir :) My bad. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @MartinBarker If I helped with my answer, a simple up vote would definitely be encouraging.

Comment: i have that's why you're at zero, it was not me who downvoted you to start with.

Comment: :) Okay I brought you to zero also.